# javascript: get base64 of input field (type=file) in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, base64

I need to upload an image, something like this

```
<form>
    <input type="file">
</form>
```

However, I want to crop/resize the file before uploading. The cropping and resize is no problem, but how do I get the base64 from the input file element? In IE10 and the other browsers I can it like this:

```
if (this.files.length === 0) {
    return;
}

var file = this.files[0];

if (file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        cropAndResize(event.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

However, in IE9 **this.files** is undefined. How can I access the base64 of the uploaded image (without a round trip to the backend of course!) in IE9 ?
[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66ZAr/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE9 does not support the FileReader API and therefore cannot do what you want using pure JavaScript. If you want IE9 support, then you'd need to use something like [this Flash solution](https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader) in order to achieve the same result.