# Image upload and convert into base64 in not working in ie9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to upload image from local disk and convert into base 64 via canvas to pass that base64 string to third party via ajax.

Below code is working in other browser but failing in ie9. It gives error "SCRIPT5009: 'FileReader' is undefined". Please let me know what code should i use to work this on ie9

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title>Image Upload</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader"/>
        <label id="base64Text"></label><br/>
        <canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>
        <script>
            var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
            imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
            var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            function handleImage(e){
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(event){
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.onload = function(){
                        canvas.width = img.width;
                        canvas.height = img.height;
                        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
                    }
                    img.src = event.target.result;
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
                //base64

                var base64 = canvas.toDataURL();
                $('#base64Text').html('Base64: ' + base64);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your question is dublicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598654/javascript-get-base64-of-input-field-type-file-in-ie9

Comment: The File API is not supported in IE9 http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi